# Where can I find statistics about the count of words starting by a letter?

Tags: dictionaries, statistics

I have found only [this](http://phrontistery.info/ihlstats.html) statistic:

- Words by Length
- Words by First and Second Letter

But I want to find words count which start by `z` and `x` (or any other letter)

Does anybody know such stat?

Comment: Table 2 in your link seems to have just what you want.

Comment: @TonyK it seems not full. The english vocabulary contain about one million of words. That table about 20-30k =(

Comment: @EugenKonkov once you get past 20K the words are fairly uncommon, and so stats using them will be very misleading.

Comment: Also, though it may seem strange, you may want to ask this on regular stackexchange.SE. They are a more likely knowledgeable about finding resources for writing NLP software.

Comment: Buy the 20-volume set of the Oxford dictionary and count the pages for each letter.  Won't be exact, but pretty close!

Comment: grep “^z” /usr/dict/words | wc -w

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can be closed as off-topic on ELU and resubmitted on ELU.Meta.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: This question is about language usage: which words are used often, which workds are not.

Comment: 'Where can I find statistics about ...?' is a request for resources; these belong on ELU.meta. Please check in the Help Center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thinks this might be what you are looking for, Scrabble dictionary statistics for 187630 words: https://www.unscramblerer.com/scrabble-twl-dictionary-statistics/ it has percentages as well as numbers for **words starting with**, **words ending with** and **words containing** all letters of the alphabet. There are also stats for word lengths.

English language obviously has more words than 187630, but they will get longer and more obscure.

Answer (score 0):

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/list/z/1) can be searched by letter.

The link I have cited has three pages worth of words starting with "z", and you will also be able to search words starting with "[x](https://www.dictionary.com/list/x/1)" or any other letter of the alphabet.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/) is an aggregating dictionary, i.e. it collects and displays words from various dictionaries. **You will probably need to count the words manually though**. There doesn't seem to be a total for each letter.

> Dictionary.com is the world’s leading online source for English definitions, synonyms, word origins, audio pronunciations, example sentences, slang phrases, idioms, word games, legal and medical terms, Word of the Day and more. For over 20 years, Dictionary.com has been helping millions of people improve their use of the English language with its free digital services

[Collins Dictionary Wordbank](http://www.collinslanguage.com/2017/03/16/collins-online-corpus/) includes meta-data. It offers a free one month trial.

> - Access authentic examples of vocabulary, word usage and grammar

and you can

> - Carry out in-depth linguistic analyses for your research thesis or 
>      dissertation

but access is not immediate.

Comment: dictionary contain a combination of words: `a number of`. Even if it provide total for each letter it can not be taken into account.

Comment: @EugenKonkov I've added an extra reference in my answer. The Collins English corpus contains 550 million words from a wide range of texts from various sources, both written and spoken, and accounts for no less than 8 varieties of English. The majority of sources in the corpus date from between 2001 and 2005 making it one of the most current corpora available.

Comment: https://corpus.byu.edu/queries.asp perhaps this link will help you too?

Comment: seems very useful for philologist. But it is complex for me (

Comment: I am looking something `Table 2` in the links I have provide. but with vocabulary which have more words